# Whats the maximum size for this type of float?

Tags: c++, floating-point

In C++, using a float variable under a 32 bit OS, whats the maximum real number you could get from a float, given an additional decimal precision? Example: 1000.2

Comment: What does "given an additional decimal precision" mean? It's already impossible to precisely represent 1000.2 as a float, or for that matter 0.1. Are you looking for the smallest two numbers that differ by 0.1, but whose nearest float representations are equal? Or something else?

Comment: Basically, whats the largest amount you can pull out of a float as a real number?

Comment: By 'real' do you mean base 10? Binary numbers are real too! :)

Comment: Yes, I mean base 10 when I say real number.

Comment: You can't hold real numbers in float, just rational ones.

Answer (score 10):

If you

```
#include <cfloat>
```

it should be

```
FLT_MAX
```

Ref: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cfloat/

Comment: The OP apparently meant "the largest number with at least one decimal digit after the dot". It doesn't make much practical sense, but anyway...

Comment: @AndreyT : That's what I took "*given an additional decimal precision? Example: 1000.2*" to mean as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <limits>


std::numeric_limits<float>().max()
```

Or maybe you're interested in the number of digits that can be represented:

```
std::numeric_limits<float>().digits10
```

See http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/numeric-limits.html

Answer (score 0):

Checkout out `cfloat`. This file is part of the C++ standard and contains constants that describe floating number limits.

If you want a specific number, you need to ask about a specific system (not just 32bit OS).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're using IEEE-754 floating point numbers, even though you did not specify - this is the most commonly used by modern processors. If you're using the binary32 form which is commonly selected by C++ compilers for the `float` type, you can see from [this table in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ieee_float#Basic_formats) that it holds just over 7 digits.

Reserving one digit to the right of the decimal point, the maximum value that can be held in 7 decimal digits is `999999.9`.

Comment: The minimum positive (subnormal) value is 2−149 ≈ 1.4 × 10−45. The minimum positive normal value is 2−126 ≈ 1.18 × 10−38. The maximum representable value is (2−2−23) × 2127 ≈ 3.4 × 1038. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format

Comment: @blaze, when I wrote this answer it wasn't clear what was being asked. There were already answers that addressed the maximum value, so I thought I'd provide the alternate interpretation. P.S. Judging by a comment from AndreyT I wasn't the only one who thought the question wasn't that straightforward.

Comment: Granted. Change a couple of chars in your answer so i can undo vote.

Comment: Alternatively, it's 24 bits in binary, so `8388607.5` would still qualify - the next higher float is 2^24, or 8388608.0

Comment: @MSalters, that's true only if you don't care about precision in the last digit - you can't represent 8388606.9 for example. You need 4 bits to the right of the decimal, so the actual largest value is 2^20-0.0625, or 1048675.9375. I thought my answer was close enough and easier to explain.